# What is the appropriate syntax for the google analytics .create method

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

according to [ga method reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference), the syntax for the .create method is:

```
ga('create', trackingId, opt_configObject);
```

But when I create a new ga account, and it gives me the auto-generated snippet of code to copy/paste into my site, it gives me a different .create syntax:

```
ga('create', trackingId, 'mydomain.com');
```

I do not see anything in the method reference that suggests that the second syntax is acceptable.

There is also a unanswered thread on the ga forum here: [ga-forum thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/analytics/create%2420method%2420argument/analytics/cvecwmcElgs/qpYxB019TDsJ).

Comment: I am using `ga('create', trackingId, {'name' : 't1'});` successfully. So I am using the object notation for arg3 and I am not including domain.

Answer (score 2):

```
ga('create', 'UA-foobar', 'mydomain.com');
```

is IMO equivalent to

```
ga('create', 'UA-foobar', { 'cookieDomain': 'mydomain.com' });
```

Some details:

I've beautified http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js via jsbeautifier.org and created this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4MRwj/2/
In line 1044 you'll find the create method of google analytics. I've only edited 3 LOC in this file. In line 1047 i added some debug info using alert() and in line 1060 and 1061 i manually call the create method using varying arguments.
Both calls result into the same debug info as you'll notice when you run it.

Comment: Benjamin ... I think that probably the answer is that the ga create method parses the argument list to determine how many args come in and what type they are (strings or object of strings). Your fiddle does show the .create method (beautified) which is very helpful, but the method still needs a thorough analysis to verify how it works within its class to understand what it is doing with the args that it receives. ... ... ... I think readers can rely on your answer though.